# Working example of Spring Social Facebook login except the sample applications on github

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

Please can somebody share links of working example of Spring Social  Facebook login except the sample applications on git hub that are provided by Spring Social people themselves. 
Especially if there is any sample code without the use of a database then that will be awesome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Spring Social Example](https://github.com/arpitaggarwal/Spring-Social) is the `Spring 3.x` implementation written  by me, you just have to change **`Facebook/Twitter`** `apikey`, `apisecret`, `callback` url and `scope` as per your requirement in **`application.properties`** [here](https://github.com/arpitaggarwal/Spring-Social/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties).

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/sunilpulugula/SpringSecuritySocialLoginExample) is the example of how to implement social login feature using spring framework.[Blog](http://sunilkumarpblog.blogspot.in/2016/04/social-login-with-spring-security.html) of this application for precise explination.This application supprts

1) Form Login : This is classic login,where there will be a form accepting username and password.User need to submit his/her user details.

2) Social Login (Facebook,twitter & linkedin) : Here social user can signin in the application using their Facebook/Twitter/linkedin accounts. Then we add support for current users to associate their social accounts with their accounts in the application,it is also called mapping social user with local user.

Comment: Nice tutorial and example, appreciate if it is in Java Config instead of XML

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below github example,

https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-social-examples

Source article : https://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-social-tutorial/

---

I don't know why you don't need the example given by Spring team. But the article and example code looks very much helpful to me. These getting started guides based on Spring Boot will help you,

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/

http://projects.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/

Clone the repo from github

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-facebook.git
```

Comment: the OP said "except the sample applications on git hub that are provided by Spring Social people themselves".

Comment: Its a tutorial explaining spring social with spring boot with a github example. Not a github link only. Plus the example is based on in memory h2 database. The OP needs to follow the step by step guide.

Comment: Honnestly, I find the information to be good. But the OP did not say he did not want a GitHub link only. He said he didn't want a sample from the Spring team. And it is not using H2 or any database