# Column 'role_id' cannot be null when trying to save user. Spring, Hibernate, Sql

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, entity

I am using spring with hibernate and when I am trying to save user it works fine, but after relaunching IDE I am getting error:

> could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

stacktrace:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'role_id' cannot be null 
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na] 
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na] 
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na] 
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488) ~[na:na] 
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40] 
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40] 
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40] 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40] 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40] 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40] 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]...
```

Full User with getters and setters.

User.java

```
package com.example.model;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @Email(message = "*Введите корректный email")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Введите email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @Length(min = 5, message = "*Пароль должен состоять не менее чем из 5 символов")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Введите пароль")
    @Transient
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "birthday")
    private String birthday;

    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name = "passportseries")
    private String passportseries;

    @Column(name = "passportnumber")
    private Integer passportnumber;

    @Column(name = "passportissue")
    private String passportissue;

    @Column(name = "passportdate")
    private String passportdate;

    @Column(name = "passportid")
    private String passportid;

    @Column(name = "birthplace")
    private String birthplace;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "adress")
    private String adress;

    @Column(name = "phonehome")
    private String phonehome;

    @Column(name = "phonemobile")
    private String phonemobile;

    @Column(name = "job")
    private String job;

    @Column(name = "jobposition")
    private String jobposition;

    @Column(name = "residencecity")
    private String residencecity;

    @Column(name = "residenceadress")
    private String residenceadress;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "nationality")
    private String nationality;

    @Column(name = "disability")
    private String disability;

    @Column(name = "pensioner")
    private String pensioner;

    @Column(name = "income")
    private Integer income;

    @Column(name = "military")
    private String military;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private int active;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;



    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getPassportseries() {
        return passportseries;
    }

    public void setPassportseries(String passportseries) {
        this.passportseries = passportseries;
    }

    public Integer getPassportnumber() {
        return passportnumber;
    }

    public void setPassportnumber(Integer passportnumber) {
        this.passportnumber = passportnumber;
    }

    public String getPassportissue() {
        return passportissue;
    }

    public void setPassportissue(String passportissue) {
        this.passportissue = passportissue;
    }

    public String getPassportdate() {
        return passportdate;
    }

    public void setPassportdate(String passportdate) {
        this.passportdate = passportdate;
    }

    public String getPassportid() {
        return passportid;
    }

    public void setPassportid(String passportid) {
        this.passportid = passportid;
    }

    public String getBirthplace() {
        return birthplace;
    }

    public void setBirthplace(String birthplace) {
        this.birthplace = birthplace;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getAdress() {
        return adress;
    }

    public void setAdress(String adress) {
        this.adress = adress;
    }

    public String getPhonehome() {
        return phonehome;
    }

    public void setPhonehome(String phonehome) {
        this.phonehome = phonehome;
    }

    public String getPhonemobile() {
        return phonemobile;
    }

    public void setPhonemobile(String phonemobile) {
        this.phonemobile = phonemobile;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    public void setJob(String job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    public String getJobposition() {
        return jobposition;
    }

    public void setJobposition(String jobposition) {
        this.jobposition = jobposition;
    }

    public String getResidencecity() {
        return residencecity;
    }

    public void setResidencecity(String residencecity) {
        this.residencecity = residencecity;
    }

    public String getResidenceadress() {
        return residenceadress;
    }

    public void setResidenceadress(String residenceadress) {
        this.residenceadress = residenceadress;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getNationality() {
        return nationality;
    }

    public void setNationality(String nationality) {
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }

    public String getDisability() {
        return disability;
    }

    public void setDisability(String disability) {
        this.disability = disability;
    }

    public String getPensioner() {
        return pensioner;
    }

    public void setPensioner(String pensioner) {
        this.pensioner = pensioner;
    }

    public Integer getIncome() {
        return income;
    }

    public void setIncome(Integer income) {
        this.income = income;
    }

    public String getMilitary() {
        return military;
    }

    public void setMilitary(String military) {
        this.military = military;
    }

    public int getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(int active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

Role.java

```
package com.example.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="role_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="role")
    private String role;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }


}
```

SQL:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.9, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: spring-security-tutorial
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.11-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `role`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `role`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `role` (
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;


--
-- Table structure for table `user`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(255) not null,
  `birthday` date not null,
  `gender` varchar(255) not null,
  `passportseries` varchar(2) not null,
  `passportnumber` int(11) not null,
  `passportissue` varchar(255) not null,
  `passportdate` date not null,
  `passportid` varchar(20) not null,
  `birthplace` varchar(255) not null,
  `city` varchar(255) not null,
  `adress` varchar(255) not null,
  `phonehome` varchar(255) null,
  `phonemobile` varchar(255) null,
  `job` varchar(255) null,
  `jobposition` varchar(255) null,
  `residencecity` varchar(255) not null,
  `residenceadress` varchar(255) not null,
  `status` varchar(255) not null,
  `nationality` varchar(255) not null,
  `disability` varchar(255) not null,
  `pensioner` varchar(255) not null,
  `income` int(11) null,
  `military` varchar(255) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;


--
-- Table structure for table `user_role`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_role`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `user_role` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`role_id`),
  KEY `FKa68196081fvovjhkek5m97n3y` (`role_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK859n2jvi8ivhui0rl0esws6o` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKa68196081fvovjhkek5m97n3y` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `role` (`role_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;


/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2016-11-16 13:21:44
```

Please help to resolve this problem. Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure where problem is, so I added more code.

UserServiceImpl.java

```
package com.example.service;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.model.Role;
import com.example.model.User;
import com.example.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.example.repository.UserRepository;

@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public User findUserByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    @Override
    public User findUserByEmail(String email, Long id) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email, id);
    }

    @Override
    public User findUserById(Long id) {
        return userRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public User findUserByPassportId(String passportid) {
        return userRepository.findByPassportId(passportid);
    }

    @Override
    public User findUserByPassportId(String passportid, Long id) {
        return userRepository.findByPassportId(passportid, id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
    @Override
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setActive(2);
        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByRole("USER");
        user.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(userRole)));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        userRepository.delete(user);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/task
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 12345678
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# ===============================
# = Thymeleaf configurations
# ===============================
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

# ==============================================================
# = Spring Security / Queries for AuthenticationManagerBuilder  
# ==============================================================
spring.queries.users-query=select email, password, active from user where email=?
spring.queries.roles-query=select u.email, r.role from user u inner join user_role ur on(u.user_id=ur.user_id) inner join role r on(ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.email=?
```

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
package com.example.configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.
            jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.
            authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
           .ignoring()
           .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/scripts/**", "/images/**");
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems like your save logic is written somewhere in your code where it gets triggered when your application starts. Can you please share where you are saving you user?

Comment: I'm saving user using JpaRepository. I had added UserServiceImpl.java where I am saving user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your User.java:

```
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_role_id") })
public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
```

And add these in your Role.java

```
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
public Set<User> getUsers(){
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users){
    this.users = users;
}
```

In your application class add `@EnableTransactionManagement`.
Also annotate your CRUD operation functions with `@Transactional`

edit your application.properties file for hibernate ddl,

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
```

Use `MySQLDialect` instead of `MySQL5Dialect`. Also add these:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=15
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=3600000
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1
```

If you are using thymeleaf 3 then,

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML
```

`HTML5LEGACY` is deprecated in thymeleaf 3

**UPDATE**

I am not sure but seems like you have some problem in spring security query. I am not very good at Spring security but as far as i know, if you use native query then you should be using like below:

```
select username, password, enabled from customers where username = ?
select username, role from customers where username = ?
```

Now, if you have other fieldnames then you can use aliases instead like:

```
select c_mobile as 'username', c_password as 'password', c_enabled as 'enabled' from customers where c_mobile = ?
select c_mobile as 'username', 'ROLE_ADMIN' from customers where c_mobile = ?
```

which means you can have name of table as per your convenience but not the field names.

But i have seen using native queries can make things complicated when integrating `spring-social` with `spring-security` in `spring-boot`.

You can use your custom native queries with JPA repository implementing `UserDetailsService` or other interfaces given in the following links.

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31628412/working-example-of-spring-social-facebook-login-except-the-sample-applications-o) , [links 2](https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-social-examples) , [link 3](http://sunilkumarpblog.blogspot.in/2016/04/social-login-with-spring-security.html) , [link 4](https://github.com/sunilpulugula/SpringSecuritySocialLoginExample)

**UPDATE**

Set the following property to true for new projects with Hibernate 5,

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = true
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. Do you mean deleting those annotations from roles and add to getRoles?

Comment: I'm getting an exception `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory`. I insert two roles(USER and ADMIN) to table (like this `INSERT INTO `role` VALUES (1,'ADMIN');`). I forget to say that.

Comment: edited yet again. now it should work without any flaw

Comment: If this solves your problem then, do mark the answer as solution and upvote if possible

Comment: I'm getting the same error "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined". Seems I'm doing something wrong. Sorry, I'm new to spring\hibernate. A few questions. 1) Why "fk_user_id" and "fk_role_id" instead of "user_id"? What does "fk" mean, I doesn't have anything like this. 2) Why we are using "create-drop"? I need to save users after relaunching IDE, so I need to use "update" then or something else? Thank you for you help!

Comment: Seems like the problem is fixed. I didn't modified User.java and Role.java, but I think additing annotations and code to app.properties helped me. Thanks for you help!

Comment: In order to establish many to many relationship, we need an intermediate table where the primary keys of both the table will be kept as foreign keys in that intermediate table. So in my answer i gave the names of those fields in the intermediate table as fk_role_id and fk_user_id. Even if your code is working fine, if you want a bidirectional manytomany mapping then use the code that i have answered. For one directional you can omit the mappedBy property and simply annotate @manytomany.

Comment: You can go through the following links for a better understanding https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/ultimate-guide-association-mappings-jpa-hibernate/

https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-map-bidirectional-many-many-association/

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: I suggested hibernate ddl to create-drop as it will automatically generate the required table based on the field name and also add the foreign keys automatically. After those changes, you can switch to update

Comment: Extremely sorry to trouble you, but could you check my other topic, please? Looks like it similar problem (but deleting user) and it was before this problem "role_id cannot be null". Unfortunately, I can't fix it for a long time.